# Passing a PHP variable between two webpages

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to make my webpage pass on a PHP variable to another webpage. I have tried using sessions but I cannot use sessions and have forwarding at the end as they both use the header. I have tried using cookies but that can only pass on one variable, I would like to use two. I have made it work with a form and an invisible field but for this page I do not want a form.

In essence I want this form to submit itself:

```
<form action="send_post2.php" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo"$_POST[name1]";?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='recipient' value='<?php echo"$_POST[recipient1]";?>'>    
</form>
```

Also how would I retrieve the variable

Comment: Submit itself? When load? After an event?

Comment: What is the problem with sessions?

Comment: It uses the header which is also used for redirects so both cannot be used at once

Comment: So is your problem that you want to pass user input (POST data) to another PHP script, which you call with a redirect? Maybe for a Post-Redirect-Get pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for retrieve value.

```
<form id="myform" action="send_post2.php" method="post">
    <input type='hidden' name='name' value='<?php echo isset($_POST['name1']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";?>'>
    <input type='hidden' name='recipient' value='<?php echo isset($_POST['recipient']) ? $_POST['recipient'] : "";?>'>    
</form>
```

For auto submit use jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(); 
});
```

Comment: What variables would I use to retrieve them?

Comment: use `$name = $_POST['name']` and `$recipient = $_POST['recipient']`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `$_POST[name1]` to `$_POST[\"name1\"]` 
and `$_POST[recipient1]` to `$_POST[\"recipient1\"]`

Please respond if it's working now.

**Edit:** You don't have to use the double quotes when using echo with $_POST. If you remove them, you can also remove the backslashes in my suggestion

Comment: It gives -  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: $_POST['name'] and $_POST['recipient']

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using cookies but that can only pass on one variable

? You can pass lots of variables via cookies - just depends upon how you structure your cookie. For instance, you could store the data within a cookie in json format (use single quotes not double - Opera rejects them otherwise )

You could send variables in querystring: ?var=value&var2=somethingelse

Why can you not access the posted vars on the second page ( presumably send_post2.php )?

Comment: Could you give an example of two pieces of data in a cookie please

Comment: setcookie( 'cookiename',"{'variable':'value','foo':'bar','php':'great'}" );

Then, when you read the cookie you can parse this as json ( after replacing single quotes for doubles - a faff i know but...) and then access as many variables as you have written to the cookie

Answer (score 0):

to pass variables between pages you can user url and `$_GET`

```
href="someurl.com/test.php?first_variable=first&second_variable=second
```

in your next page

```
$first = $_GET['first_variable'];
$sec = $_GET['second_variable'];
```

Comment: How could I set the variables to be the variables I set in PHP?

Comment: you can set the variable to the any variables you want, change `first_variable` to the one you set in PHP and also do the same for `second_variable`

Comment: So if i put $first_variable it would pass on that variable